# Form naming and model naming recommendation

Tags: angularjs

If I have a form like this

```
<form name="form" ng-submit="form.save()">
  <input type="text" name="name" ng-model="form.name">
  <button type="submit" ng-disabled="form.name.$pristine">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Here I have a form named "form", an input-field named "name" and a model named "form.name". Will the formname+fieldname ("form.name") be in conflict with the model name ("form.name") somehow? Is this bad naming practice? Or maybe this is perfectly OK and will give me no troubles?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To be honest that's a terrible Idea, naming your form the same your model. When you declare a form in Angular, a form object by the name of the form will be created on the Scope of the view's controller. Having a model object named same as the form will result in in mixing up of the 2 objects, the form object created by angular has many fields and functions of it's own, why would you want to litter your model with that? If you try running the code you posted and placing a `$watch` on form, you will notice that the model value won't even be bond properly:

```
$scope.$watch("form", function (v) {
  console.log(v);
}, true);
```

results in:

```
$addControl: function (control) {
$dirty: true
$error: Object
$invalid: false
$name: "form"
$pristine: false
$removeControl: function (control) {
$setDirty: function () {
$setPristine: function () {
$setValidity: function (validationToken, isValid, control) {
$valid: true
name: "[object Object]john"
```

Solution: Just give your model and form different names :)

Comment: Thanks, Mohammad. I hoped to avoid contrived name-sets for the (almost) same thing, like "form" and "formModel" or similar. I better then spend some calories of figuring out a set of names that do not sound so unnatural...

Comment: What I usually do is if I have a form pertaining to an entity I call the form entity name + form, such as `personnelForm`, and my model will usually be called the entity itself, such as `personnel`.

Comment: Aha, I might copy that :) Thanks again!